# UDF cause warning: CachedKafkaConsumer is not running in UninterruptibleThread (KAFKA-1894)

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

In an usual [structured_kafka_wordcount.py](https://gist.github.com/hrchu/2b2590f2f737ef430ac32b7f8edc15c0) code,

When I split lines into words by `udf` like below,

```py
my_split = udf(lambda x: x.split(' '), ArrayType(StringType()))

words = lines.select(
    explode(
        my_split(lines.value)
    )
)
```

the warning will keep showing:

> WARN CachedKafkaConsumer: CachedKafkaConsumer is not running in
>   UninterruptibleThread. It may hang when CachedKafkaConsumer's methods
>   are interrupted because of KAFKA-1894

On the other hand, when I split the lines into words by `pyspark.sql.functions.split`, everything works well.

```py
words = lines.select(
    explode(
        split(lines.value, ' ') 
    ) 
)
```

Why this happened and how to fix the warning?

This is the code I am trying to execute in practice:

```py
pattern = "(.+) message repeated (\\d) times: \\[ (.+)\\]"
prog = re.compile(pattern)


def _unfold(x):
    ret = []
    result = prog.match(x)
    if result:
        log = " ".join((result.group(1), result.group(3)))
        times = result.group(2)
        for _ in range(int(times)):
            ret.append(log)
    else:
        ret.append(x)

    return ret

_udf = udf(lambda x: _unfold(x), ArrayType(StringType()))
lines = lines.withColumn('value', explode(_udf(lines['value'])))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Other than rejecting Python UDFs *, there is nothing you can do about this problem in you code. As you can read in the exception message `UninterruptibleThread` is a workaround to Kafka bug ([KAFKA-1894](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-1894)) and is designed to prevent infinite loop, when interrupting `KafkaConsumer`.

It is not used with `PythonUDFRunner` (it probably wouldn't makes sense, to introduce special case there).

Personally I wouldn't worry about it unless you experience some related issues. Your Python code will never interact directly with `KafkaConsumer`. And if you experience any issues, there should fixed upstream - in that case I recommend creating a [JIRA ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK).

---

* Your `unfold` function can be rewritten with SQL functions, but it will be a hack. Add message count as integer:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import concat_ws, col, expr, coalesce, lit, regexp_extract, when

p = "(.+) message repeated (\\d) times: \\[ (.+)\\]"

lines = spark.createDataFrame(
    ["asd message repeated 3 times: [ 12]", "some other message"], "string"
)

lines_with_count = lines.withColumn(
   "message_count", coalesce(regexp_extract("value", p, 2).cast("int"), lit(1)))
```

Use it to `explode`

```py
exploded = lines_with_count.withColumn(
     "i", 
      expr("explode(split(repeat('1', message_count - 1),''))")
).drop("message_count", "i")
```

and extract:

```py
exploded.withColumn(
    "value",
    when(
        col("value").rlike(p),
         concat_ws(" ", regexp_extract("value", p, 1), regexp_extract("value", p, 3))
    ).otherwise(col("value"))).show(4, False)


# +------------------+
# |value             |
# +------------------+
# |asd 12            |
# |asd 12            |
# |asd 12            |
# |some other message|
# +------------------+
```